# What's the difference between ui.alert and Browser.msgBox?

Tags: google-apps-script

When working with Google Scripting, there's a `Browser.msgBox();` ([Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser)) and `ui.alert();` ([Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)).  What is the difference between the two?  They appear to do the exact same thing.

There are more methods within, such as `Browser.inputBox();` and `ui.prompt();` which again, appear to be identical.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ***Browser Class*** is only available to a Spreadsheet.  The ***Ui Class*** can be more widely used.  Unfortunately, the documentation for ***Class Ui*** only shows an example of the `getUi()` method with the ***SpreadsheetApp*** Class.  But `getUi()` is available to ***DocumentApp***.

### DocumentApp.getUi()

[image: get Ui Class]

And to:

```
FormApp.getUi()
```

If you try to call `Browser.msgBox()` from the wrong context, you'll get an error:

> Cannot call Browser.msgBox() from this context; have you tried Logger.log() instead?

`Browser.msgBox()` is easier to use in a Spreadsheet script.  You don't need to first use `var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();`

To compare:

```
Browser.msgBox('prompt here');
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('prompt here');
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  It seems to me that Browser would then be deprecated.  Is there a reason it's still around?

Comment: I've wondered the same. My guess is that the implementation of `Browser` is based directly on `Ui` now, so there is no compelling reason to deprecate it and annoy users. After all, Google has so many other ways to annoy us...

Comment: Does DocumentApp.getUi() allow dialogs to be used from the mobile Sheets app?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I haven't used the mobile Sheets app, and haven't been using Apps Script for a while.